# можно ли в файле с классами вызвать класс? (не из другого файла)

Tags: pyqt

```
THEME = Light                  
BACKLIGHT = Green              

class Light:
    background = "#F2F2F2"       

class Green:
    backlight = "#AAA6C42E"
```

### еще пример:

```
class Test:
    test = "test"
    print (test)

tt = Test()

print (test)
```

почему не работает? что не так?

блин, точняк...     print (test) заменить на     print (tt.test)

### добился результата:

```
ORIENTATION = "Horizontal"              # Vertical, Horizontal
class Vertical:
    test = "Vertical"

class Horizontal:
    test = "Horizontal"

if    ORIENTATION == "Vertical":    Orientation = Vertical()
elif  ORIENTATION == "Horizontal":  Orientation = Horizontal()

print (Orientation.test)
```

Comment: Что конкретно вы хотите сделать? Да, создание экземпляра класса возможно в том же модуле, где он и объявлен (**раньше**, чем вызов).

Comment: то есть мне надо просто спустить ниже? THEME = Light  или THEME = self.Light ??? как вызов произвести?

Comment: добавил еще пример...